# php scrape all iframes src from a website sitemap

Tags: php, arrays, simple-html-dom

I am trying to scrape a website in order to create a list of all the the iframes source that are in it, in order to do so I use the simple_html_dom php library .

I parse each of the links and in every link I search for an iframe, I the iframe exists i ask the code to bring me its src and the page it was taken from.

What i am doing is:

1. grab all the links from the desired page.
2. convert them in to one big array in order to avoid server crushes.
3. all the links are relative so i add the the main url in the begining.
4. i loop all the urls and search for iframes in the pages.

what happens is that it works good for 20 row and than i get this errors:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.achva.ac.ilhttp://www.achva.ac.il/לימודי-תעודה-והשתלמויות): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap\scrap.php on line 61
```

for some reason I keep getting errors:

this is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
        th{
            font-weight: 800;
            border: 1px solid lightblue;
        }
        td{
            border: 1px solid lightblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<?php 

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.achva.ac.il/sitemap');
//Create a new DOM document
$dom = new DOMDocument;

//Parse the HTML. The @ is used to suppress any parsing errors
//that will be thrown if the $html string isn't valid XHTML.
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

//Get all links. You could also use any other tag name here,
//like 'img' or 'table', to extract other tags.
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

//Iterate over the extracted links and display their URLs
$arr = [];
foreach ($links as $link){
    array_push($arr, 'http://www.achva.ac.il'.$link->getAttribute('href'));
}


$result = count($arr);
echo $result;
?>

<?php  


function urlOk($url) {
    $headers = @get_headers($url);
    if($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK') return true;
    else return false;
}

*/
include('simple_html_dom.php');

echo '<table><tr><th>id</th><th>Video src</th><th>Site page</th></tr>';
$i = 19;
$page_number = 1;

foreach($arr as $urlx){

    echo $urlx;

        $scrap_url = file_get_html($urlx);

        if (preg_match('#^http?://(?:[^.]+\.)*achva\.ac.il/#i', $urlx))     
        {


        $div = $scrap_url->find('iframe');
        if($div){

            foreach ($div as $key) {

                echo '<tr><td>' . $i . '</td>';

                $src = $key->attr['src'];
                echo '<td>' . $src . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' .$urlx . '</td></tr>';
                $page_number++;

            }

        }else{
            echo '<tr><td>' . $i . '</td><td>no iframe in this tage</td><td>' . $urlx . '</td></tr>';

        }

        $i++;
    }
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe it's a dodgy link in the page you're scraping?

Comment: I try avoid bad urls with line '  if (preg_match('#^http?://(?:[^.]+\.)*achva\.ac.il/#i', $urlx))' I have no idea what causes the problem...

Comment: might be a valid link from a syntactic point of view, but doesn't actually exist in reality? Therefore when you come to try and fetch it, you get a connection error such as the one you're seeing

Comment: You were right, there was a dodgy link, I added this function in order to avoid it,   `if(preg_match('http://www.achva.ac.il',$link)){
   array_push($arr, $link->getAttribute('href'));
 }else{
     array_push($arr, 'http://www.achva.ac.il'.$link->getAttribute('href'));
 }` any way it still stops after 20 row

Comment: it still stops with the same error?

Comment: yes, for some reason i dosen't avoid geting this link

Comment: this are the errors i receive `Warning: file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap\simple_html_dom.php on line 75

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.achva.ac.ilhttp://www.achva.ac.il/%D7%90%D7%92%D7%95%D7%93%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\scrap\simple_html_dom.php on line 75`

Comment: that's a DNS error - it's saying it can't find achva.ac.il. Why it would do that only after multiple requests have succeeded I don't know. Possibly some policy limit has been exceeded. There are plenty of existing sources online dealing with the possible causes of the error https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Warning%3A+file_get_contents()%3A+php_network_getaddresses%3A+getaddrinfo+failed%3A+No+such+host+is+known.&oq=Warning%3A+file_get_contents()%3A+php_network_getaddresses%3A+getaddrinfo+failed%3A+No+such+host+is+known.&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.303j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 .